# error in accessing DataContext class from winforms inside folder

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, namespaces, datacontext

I am creating a project where my win forms are inside the folder "Presentation". Also I've another folder DAL.

When I am trying to access DataContext from the winforms inside "Presentation" I am getting error, "**the type of namespace could not be found (are you missing a using directives or an assembly reference)**". Same error is given when I try to access DataContext from DAL.

```
// UserLoginForm inside Presentation Folder
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using DAL;

namespace LibraryMS
{
    public partial class UserLoginForm : Form
    {
        AppUser users = new AppUser();

        DataClassesDataContext dbContext = new DataClassesDataContext();  // getting error here

        // remaining code

// AppUser inside DAL       
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Text;

namespace DAL
{
    public class AppUser
    {
        SqlHelper helper = new SqlHelper();     

        DataClassesDataContext dbContext = new DataClassesDataContext(); // getting error here

        // remaining code
```

My project structure is ::

```
Solution 'LibraryMS'
> DAL // contains classes for database tables
    > AppUser
    > Address
> LibraryMS
        > DataClasses.dbml
          DataClasses.designer.cs
        >Presentation // win forms
```

How to solve this error? Can I make folder for dbml too? How can I access DataContext from the cs files inside folders?

location of DataContext class :: **DataClasses.designer.cs**

```
namespace LibraryMS
{
    using System.Data.Linq;
    using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Linq.Expressions;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System;


    public partial class DataClassesDataContext : System.Data.Linq.DataContext
    { // ....
```

Comment: Namespaces are only related to the folder structure if you make them so. What namespace have you used for `AppUser` and `Address`?

Comment: You haven't shown the `namespace`, just more `using` statements. After the using statements, there will be something like `namespace DAL { public class AppUser` or some such.

Comment: I've shown all that I am using without any modification.

Comment: ok let me modify my code.

Comment: Where is `DataClassesDataContext` defined?

Comment: location of DataContext class :: DataClasses.designer.cs